# Angular 7 - Browser Refresh always redirecting to homepage

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

What's the best way to retain the user on same page after browser refresh.

**Example:**
User is in [www.domain.com/page1](http://www.domain.com/page1). When he refreshes the browser, the router redirects to [www.domain.com/home](http://www.domain.com/home) which is the default routing.

I can achieve this by using `HashLocationStrategy`. But it adds additional `#` in the url. Ex: [www.domain.com/#/page1](http://www.domain.com/#/page1), which I want to avoid.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "page1",
    component: page1Component
  },
  { 
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home', 
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }

];

providers: [{
   provide: LocationStrategy, 
   useClass: HashLocationStrategy
}]
```

Also, I have done the required apache web server configurations as per the https://angular.io/guide/deployment

I understand angular is SPA and after root everything is virtual. **But still, is there a better way to achieve this without `#`?**

Comment: Can you comment the apache configuration and try

Comment: I tried that too. But i didn't see any difference. Why do you think that makes a difference? Do you mean, 404 rewrite rule to index.html creating problem?

Comment: In a clean code it won't redirect to home

Comment: In local development, its working fine. The issue occurring only when i deploy to apache web servers. If you say clean code, what exactly you referring to?

Comment: the problem is 99% in apache configuration. it sends 30x redirect when trying to get  /page1 but instead it should just response with 200 index.html

Comment: Did you tried `<base>` tag in the html doc

Comment: @Andrei: let me cross check one more time with apache configurations. Thx.

Comment: @Andrei. I cross checked the apache rules. /page1 status is 302 Found and then redirecting to index.html with 200 status. as per the rewrite rules provided by angular, this seems to the right behavior. After index.html 200 redirection, the router is not redirecting back to /page1. Seems like i am missing something here. any more clues ?

Comment: @Kiv exactly. `/page1 status is 302 Found ` that is where you miss your original url. It should send `200 index.html` at this step and everything will work because angular will handle the rest

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question, you can consider using lazy loading feature modules for each feature you have.

See my my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9auukd) for more details.

When you refresh the stackblitz page, it stay on the same page.

Comment: I have lazy loaded modules in place. The problem is only in the server. That too only when i refresh the browser or use direct urls.

Comment: @KiV did you get any solution for the above problem you raised. I am also facing the same problem

Comment: link is broken.