# Refreshing the page or entering the URL in browser redirects to home page angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I am working on angular 7 application. When i navigate the page from one to another using routerlink option, it is working fine.

```
 <a class="dropdown-item pt-3 pb-3 border-bottom" routerLink="/proposals">Proposals</a>

 <a class="dropdown-item pt-3 pb-3 border-bottom" routerLink="/datapartners">Data Partners</a>
```

it will redirect to specific page and render the corresponding component. **but when i refresh the page / enters the different URL in browser, automatically it will direct to home page for all the cases.**  that means routing working fine via router link not through browser URL.

**It is working fine in all the cases for local environment.the issue happening only in deployed server.**

```
https://localhost:4200/proposals  - working fine in all the cases locally.

https://x.com/app/proposals  - working only via router link  not through browser URL.
```

I had tried to set the basehref="/app/" attribute in index.html but no luck.

Below is the routing component code snippet.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home', // Core Framework will handle this route path - /login. If there's any change App Team can update accordingly!
    pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [LoginGuard]
   },



  {
    path: 'proposals',
    component: ProposalsComponent,
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    //pathMatch: 'full',
    //  canActivate: [EMSGuard],
    canActivate: [LoginGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
    //  canActivate: [EMSGuard],
    canActivate: [LoginGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
    //  canActivate: [EMSGuard],
    canActivate: [LoginGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'whatisnew',
    component: WhatisnewComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
    //  canActivate: [EMSGuard],
    canActivate: [LoginGuard]
  },



  {
    path: 'datapartners',
    component: DatapartnersComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
    //  canActivate: [EMSGuard],
    canActivate: [LoginGuard]
  },






  // #route4: wild card route
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: try `basehref="./"`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `LocationStrategy`

```
providers: [{
   provide: LocationStrategy, 
   useClass: HashLocationStrategy
}]
```

[Angular 7 - Browser Refresh always redirecting to homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55288583/angular-7-browser-refresh-always-redirecting-to-homepage)

Answer (score 0):

This need to be at the bottom of the array , since it works on first match principal

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home', // Core Framework will handle this route path - /login. If there's any change App Team can update accordingly!
    pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [LoginGuard]
   },
```

Comment: I hope he reloading the browser with existing path. :(

Comment: And it is based on matched condition instead of top and bottom ...